# What is the difference between root and aggregate root in DDD

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

My friend came across this question in an interview which we still not able to find answer for.

What is the difference between root and aggregate root in DDD?

We are aware that there is aggregate root but not aware of root concept in DDD so is this a valid question and if so then what is the difference?

Comment: Not a valid question unless the interviewer is trying to catch your friend, wich is unlikely according my experience in interviews in companies with ignorants DDD wannabes.

Comment: That interview was in Amazon but I do agree, I do not see this as a valid question even if it comes from an engineer in amazon or anywhere else.

Answer (score 4):

In the contexts that I am familiar with, "root" is an abbreviation of "aggregate root"; an aggregate may contain more than one entity, but the application layer is only allowed to interact with the entity that plays the role of the aggregate root.

See Chapter 6 of the Evans Domain Driven Design book.

Answer (score 0):

Can an entity exist outside of another entity?  If not, it's not the aggregate root.  An OrderItem is an entity, but doesn't have any reality outside the context of an Order.

Second on review Chapter 6 of DDD.